# How to get a unique numbers for the x position ?

Tags: random, bitmap, android-canvas

I am trying to get  a unique random x position to draw a bitmap, the only problem I have is that the random numbers are very similar. so  how to make these unique numbers  different from each others by 5 number between each number, the sequence should be like 5 10 15 20 25.

```
 private String generateXPoistion(String poistion, int numberaOfDigits)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<numberaOfDigits;i++)
            {
                poistion +=  randomGenerator.nextInt(9) + 1;  // the 1 to avoid zero 
            }
            return poistion;
        }
//In the method storeApp, I am using the KeyValue of the hashMap as an x position to draw the bitmap. 

        public void storeApple(Apple apple) 
        {      
            String newId =  generateXPoistion("",3);

                while(appleMap.get(newId) != null )
                {
                    newId = generateXPoistion("",3);
                }
                int foo = Integer.parseInt(newId);
              apple.setPos(foo);
            appleMap.put(newId,apple);
        }
```

Comment: Generate sequential integers but then multiply (scale) them by the desired stagger distance of 5.

Comment: I will try to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have

```
poistion +=  randomGenerator.nextInt(9) + 1
```

change it to

```
poistion +=  5 * (randomGenerator.nextInt(9) + 1)
```

Outcomes of 1, 2, 3,... will be scaled to 5, 10, 15,...